# How do you sequentially handle trying multiple lines of code that might throw errors?

Tags: python, error-handling

Currently I have a piece of code that operates as such:

```
try: 
   function1()

except:
   function2()

except: 
   function3()
```

But I get thrown the error: default 'except:' must be last. Basically if function1 fails, try function2. If function 2 fails, try function 3.

How would I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to nest the exception handlers to match your handling logic.

```
try: 
    function1()

except:
    try:
        function2()

    except: 
        function3()
```

If you control the function code, then I suggest that you have each one return a status code ... say, 0 for success and -1 for failure.

```
for f in [function1, function2, function3]:
    if f():  break
```

Does that handle your use case?  You keep executing functions until one succeeds.

Comment: Remember to pick a best answer.  This lets SO archive the question neatly, and I think it gives you a few points, as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to create longer chains of error handlers you might consider using a decorator.

```
def try_except_decorator(except_func):
    def decorator(try_func):
        def wrapped():
            try:
                try_func()
            except:
                except_func()
        return wrapped
    return decorator


def function3():
    print('function3')


@try_except_decorator(function3)
def function2():
    print('function2')
    raise ValueError


@try_except_decorator(function2)
def function1():
    print('function1')
    raise ValueError


function1()
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you don't control `functionX`, you could write a class that generically wraps functions and suppresses exceptions. This is similar to the decorator idea, but if you can change the source to add the decorator... why not just change the function itself?

```
class Supressor:

    def __init__(self, func, exceptions=(Exception,), exc_val=None):
        self._func = func
        self._exc = exceptions
        self._exc_val = exc_val
        try:
            self.__doc__ = func.__doc__
        except AttributeError:
            passs

    def __call__(self, *args, **kw):
        try:
            retval = self._func(*args, **kw)
        except Exception as e:
            for okay in self._exc:
                if isinstance(e, okay):
                    return self._exc_val
            else:
                raise

# defined in other module but placed here for test
def function1():
    print('f1')
    raise ValueError()
    return 1

def function2():
    print('f2')
    raise KeyError()
    return 2

def function3():
    print('made it')
    return 3

function1 = Supressor(function1)
function2 = Supressor(function2)
function3 = Supressor(function3)

if function1() is None:
    if function2() is None:
        function3()
```